# Rhom: Sorting a column after making all values to down case, but output as the original with case preserved

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes, rhom

I have been trying to sort the output of select query based upon one column as like this,

```
users = User.find(:all, :select => ['name'], :order => ["name"], :orderdir => ["ASC"], :conditions => {:deleted => 'false'})
```

But this sorts the list based upon the case separately and giving below output,

```
Ashis
Ram
lucky
syam
```

Which should be like this

```
Ashis
lucky
Ram
syam
```

So i tried this way and got the output

```
users = User.find_by_sql("select name from user where deleted = 'false' order by lower(name) ASC")
```

I'm just wondering the way to achieve this using `.find`. How to do so ?

Comment: how about `:order => ["lower(name)"]`

Comment: Yes i have tried that already, but no luck. Its giving the same result as `:order => ["name"]`.